# calculating the same moving average on a set of stocks

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a single stock, I would calculate a moving average as:

```
frame = sql.read_frame(...)
frame['ewma'] = ewma(frame['px'], span=15)
```

So, if instead, I have a frame full of price data, one series for each stock:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 819 entries, 2011-06-30 00:00:00 to 2014-08-19 00:00:00
Freq: B
Data columns (total 10 columns):
StockA       292  non-null values
StockB       303  non-null values
...
dtypes: float64(10)
```

...how would I, using say a Panel or hierarchical index, most efficiently compute the moving average for all stocks in the frame, in one go? I'd want other stats too, if that makes a difference...

Comment: `df.apply(pd.ewma, span=15)`

Comment: okay, but how do I then store the results in the Panel/hierarchically indexed data frame?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want additional columns with a suffix, you can just assign to the desired column names.

```
ewma_col = [c + '_ewma' for c in df]
df[ewma_col] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x, span=15))
```

If you wanted to set up a MultiIndex, you could do something like this, first setting up the MultiIndex, then adding the ewma entries.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['price']])
ewma_col = [(c, 'ewma') for c, _ in df]
df[ewma_col] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x, span=15))
```